# Conversion of regenerative receiver to tranciever

Tags: regenerative

The regenerative receiver contains a generator, is it possible to turn it into a simple transceiver using the same coil for tuning both to receive and transmit?

The circuit below works in a wide range of frequencies, so it's pretty tempting to have this wide range available for transmission. I wasn't however able to find any regenerative transceivers, is there something fundamentally wrong with them?

[image: RF-part of wide-band regenerative receiver]

Comment: The oscillator in OP's circuit oscillates at very low current. It **does** radiate a small signal out the antenna while receiving.  Search for **PIXIE transceiver** for something that switches between transmit & receive, radiating more power while transmitting.

Comment: The main issue would be, transmitting takes orders of magnitude more power than receiving.  It would be easier to just store (much more) of that rectified voltage, and use a separate transmitter from there.  For energy storage, NP0 ceramic caps likely have the lowest leakage (but worst volumetric efficiency.)

Comment: btw, since I think yours is Ukrainian name – shouldn't you have an easier time getting western components than (legacy) CCCP-produced transistors like the (ever crappy) KT361? Seriously, regenerative receivers are a thing that was "easier" at the time where transistors didn't exist or simply weren't broadly available, and gain stages used expensive vacuum tubes. Since ca mid/late 1960s, superhet receivers are not harder, but still *a lot* better.

Comment: @glen_geek, yeah, I ordered 2 Pixie kits, but haven't assembled them yet. They work with crystal and thus fixed frequency only. I was something easy, comparable to Pixies, but capable of switching a frequency. And, the direct conversion receiver part of Pixie works with CW signals only, while regens work will all kinds of modulations

Comment: @MarcusMüller, we have both western and old soviet components available. Last weekend I assembled a voltage regulator for a lead battery charger using a 40-year-old KT844. Linear and 10A of current :-)
For the schematic above I will use probably 2N2907

Comment: ah that's rather cool :)

Answer (score 1):

> *I wasn't however able to find any regenerative transceivers, is there
> something fundamentally wrong with them?*

Trying to merge the regenerative receiver with a simple amplitude modulator is bound to cause problems. Regenerative receivers operate on the cusp of instability and it's just not worth the hassle to try and figure out how you could merge receiver and modulator effectively and reliably.

The regenerative receiver is *almost* an oscillator when set up correctly and, it takes its stimulus from the signal being tuned into so, even if you did decide to try this as an experiment, you would still need to make a tuned oscillator to stimulate the regenerative receiver but, if you have a tuned oscillator there's no need to use any regenerative circuits.

An oscillator is a regenerative circuit in its own right except it's pushed just far enough to self-oscillate whereas the regenerative receiver isn't (and needs stimulus).

Not a sensible idea in my opinion; design a variable frequency oscillator and a simple broadcast amplitude modulation circuit and this will prove easier than trying to merge things.

Comment: absolutely agreeing with this. Note that if you want to use the recovered carrier from your reception for setting your transmit frequency, you will need some stable oscillator that you adjust in frequency from your receiver while it's receiving and gets left alone while you're transmitting (since you'd only be building yet another oscillating feedback loop). So, if you want that, a PLL running off your receive signal (and not the regenerator output) and an independent transmitter is pretty much the only way I see.